# Restrict EditText to signed decimal numbers

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing the application that has to display to a user a dynamically created table of EditText widgets.

My current code:

```
      /**
      * Create and display the table of EditTexts on the screen
      * @param x Number of columns
      * @param y Number of rows
      */
        private void createTable(int x, int y) {
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
            etGrid = new EditText[y][x];
            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                    EditText et = new EditText(this);

                    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL 
                              | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

                    et.setSingleLine();
                    et.setMinimumWidth(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/x);
                    etGrid[i][j] = et;
                    row.addView(et);
                }
                table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            }

        }
```

The problem is in this line, which doesn't work at all:

```
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL 
                                  | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

On my Kindle Fire I can either restrict to decimal values with `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` or signed with `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED`, but not to signed decimal. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: I don't really see any problem with your code. You could try to use .setRawInputType(); instead but if that also doesn't work its probably something Amazone screwed up with the Kindle

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Reference : [setRawInputType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919416/556975)

**EDIT:**

I tried this and it works for me.

Just be sure with this :

You have to remove this attribute `android:inputType` from your `et` **edittext** from the `xml layout` file. Otherwise `setRawInputType` changes will not be reflected.

Thanks.

Comment: This generally works, but minus and dot get inserted as unknown characters into an EditText.

Comment: @bvk256 please see the edit with the solution I have posted. This works for me perfectly.

Comment: There is no definition of any EditText in the XML layout file since all of them are created dynamically during the runtime.

Answer (score 11):

It is extremely important to *ALWAYS* have `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` before the other options: `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`, or else the keypad won't be numeric!

Comment: It is a regular OR operation. The order does not matter at all. A + B is the same as B + A.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed turned out to be a bug in Amazon's Android. Since I'm writing the application for myself there is a little workaround that perfectly suited me:

1. Set `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`
2. Implement a custom key filter to enforce the correct format. I've used [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5208823/685948).