# Unable to enter minus sign for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have following `EditText` element, when the keyboard shows up to enter value here there is a `-` sign shown there but nothing happens when you click it? can anyone tell me why.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kernelb11"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewb"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginOne"
    android:background="@color/white1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:text="0" >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android InputType layout parameter - how to allow negative decimals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061261/android-inputtype-layout-parameter-how-to-allow-negative-decimals)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

if `input type` as `number` then `- sign` will not be accepted, so you need to use `input type` as `numberSigned` like

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

or

```
android:inputType="text"
android:digits="0123456789-"
```

inside `EditText`

Answer (score 2):

If your number is to be decimal you can declare: `android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"`

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="number"`

A numeric only field. Corresponds to `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` | `TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL`.

use

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

Can be combined with number and its other options to allow a signed number. Corresponds to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Comment: Than what to do for `-` what `inputType` should i specify?