# Enter +/- float value in edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to restrict a user can enter only positive and negative real value in edit text.
Here is my code

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/value"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    >
```

By above code i am able to enter real value But can't enter negative real value(like "-3.7") how it is possible.
Is there any other property for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another attribute `numberSigned` which can be combined with `numberDecimal` as `numberDecimal|numberSigned`.

This is a duplicate of the following: [Android InputType layout parameter - how to allow negative decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061261/android-inputtype-layout-parameter-how-to-allow-negative-decimals)

The Android documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED